# Access Inbox message from Android application

Tags: android, sms

I need a help in Android sms application. I am sending a message from my android application to a mobile number. I need to check if the message has been delivered in INBOX of that mobile number from my application. I need to check the message sent to mobile number has been delivered. Ie. Desitnation matches. How to access INBOX messge from android application. Please guide me in this issue. It will be of great help if someone helps me with sample working example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to Access INBOX messagr from android application, answer is below,

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
{
  // Retrieve sms
  // see column "address" for comparing

  // Then update the sms and set the column "read" to 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public static final Uri SMS_INBOX_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

 Cursor cursor = managedQuery(SMS_INBOX_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{TextSmsColumns.ID, TextSmsColumns.ADDRESS,
            TextSmsColumns.DATE, TextSmsColumns.BODY}, null, null, TextSmsColumns.DATE + " DESC");

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
    {
        builder.append("         ID-"+i);
        String s= "  Address:  "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TextSmsColumns.ADDRESS))
        + "  Body:  "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TextSmsColumns.BODY))
        + "  Date:  "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TextSmsColumns.DATE));
        builder.append(s);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
```